# Add the function of finding the minimum element to the "Queue" structure

Tags: c#, algorithm, function, min

**Welcome all**.
 I understand the principle of the queue, having implemented it myself. 
I need to supplement the code with a function to find the minimum element among the currently existing ones. Some points in this code were not done by myself, and in principle, I just started working with object-oriented programming. 
**Give me an idea of how to refer to elements and which loop to use to find the minimum element.** 
**Thanks**.

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start(); // начало замера времени
            long before = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
            int min = int.MaxValue;
            Queue queue = new Queue(); // Структура очередь
            File.WriteAllText(@"output.txt", string.Empty);
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"input.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default)) // Считывание файла input.txt
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) // пока строки в файле не null
                {
                    if (line[0] == '+') // если "+", добавить элемент со значением, стоящим после "+"
                    {
                        var pattern = new Regex(@"\d+");
                        var numberStr = pattern.Match(line).Groups[0].Value;
                        queue.Enqueue(int.Parse(numberStr));
                    }
                    if (line[0] == '-') // если "-", выпустить элемент из очереди (first in - first out)
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"output.txt", true, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(queue.Dequeue());
                        }
                    }
                    if (line[0] == '?') // если "?", вывести наименьший элемент в очереди
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"output.txt", true, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(queue.Minimum());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            long after = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
            long consumedInMegabytes = (after - before) / (1024); // замер памяти в КБ
            Console.WriteLine($"Затраты памяти (КБ): {consumedInMegabytes}");
            watch.Stop(); // конец замера времени
            Console.WriteLine($"Время выполнения (миллисекунд): {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");


        }
    }

    public class QueueItem
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public QueueItem Next { get; set; }
    }

    public class Queue
    {
        QueueItem head;
        QueueItem tail;

        public void Enqueue(int value) // функция добавления элемента в очередь
        {
            if (head == null)
                tail = head = new QueueItem { Value = value, Next = null };
            else
            {
                var item = new QueueItem { Value = value, Next = null };
                tail.Next = item;
                tail = item;
            }
        }

        public int Dequeue() // функция удаления элемента из очереди
        {
            if (head == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
            var result = head.Value;
            head = head.Next;
            if (head == null)
                tail = null;
            return result;
        }
        public int Minimum()
        {
            // WHAT I NEED DO
        }
    }
```

Comment: By the way, the output sequence of the minimum element must match the order read from the document

Comment: Don't know if that's just to play around, but `Stopwatch` is _not_ a Benchmarking Tool.

Comment: Also: If you comment your code in english, you increase the number of people able to read them drastically ;)

Comment: _"Give me an idea of how to refer to elements and which loop to use to find the minimum element"_ . You basically have two options: Keep track of min Value by updating it on Dequeue / Enqueue or iterating the complete queue each time. Both have their obvious pros and cons.

Comment: The main observation for this problem is that once you enqueue a value `x`, all earlier enqueued values `y` with `y > x` become irrelevant. This should allow you to keep a second queue, which handles `Minimum()` and `Dequeue` in `O(1)` time and `Enqueue` in amortized `O(n)` time.

Comment: Thanks for the answers already provided.
Can I see how to implement it? Thanks.
P.S. A teacher at my university claims that Stopwatch should be used for testing.

Comment: For testing what? At max you can test if you see an execution time greater than X. For everything else a proper benchmarking tool should be used. Like Benchmark.Net for example. It takes warmup, JIT, etc. into account.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we enqueue these value:

```
index: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
value: 5 3 8 4 2 1 6 3 7 2
```

What is the correct value of `Minimum` after item 3 is enqueued? Well, it depends. It can be `3` (if item 1 hasn't been dequeued yet) or it can be `4`. But it can never be `5` or `8`, because `4 < 5` and `4 < 8`, no matter which values have been dequeued.

So we can build a data structure with the potential answers of `Minimum`, after each enqueue:

```
index:     0   1      2      3   4   5      6      7         8      9
value:     5   3      8      4   2   1      6      3         7      2
minimum:  [5] [3] [3, 8] [3, 4] [2] [1] [1, 6] [1, 3] [1, 3, 7] [1, 2]
```

See that the `minimum` list is always sorted. If we encounter a new value that is larger than the largest item in the list, we append it. If it is smaller, we replace all larger values by the new one.

---

Now, what happens on dequeue? Let's take the `minimum` list after index 8 (because it happened to be the longest / most interesting) and see what happens on dequeue:

```
index:          0         1         2         3         4      5      6   7   8
dequeue:        5         3         8         4         2      1      6   3   7
minimum: [1, 3, 7] [1, 3, 7] [1, 3, 7] [1, 3, 7] [1, 3, 7] [3, 7] [3, 7] [7] []
```

See that we just remove the minimum value from the list when we dequeue that same value.

---

Now all we need is a data structure that allows us to inspect the first element (in `O(1)` time), remove the first element (in `O(1)` time), and add a new value to the end (which requires removing amortized `O(n)` elements from the end as well).

Since this is a university exercise, I'll leave the actual implementation to you, but this should hopefully push you in the right direction.